# Node child spawn of Pouchdb give ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, pouchdb

Note: This is on Windows 10.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var db = spawn('pouchdb-server', ['--port 5984', '-m']);
```

Also tried

```
var db = spawn('pouchdb-server', ['--port', '5984', '-m']);
```

Both give ENOENT.

This however does work:

```
var db = child_process.exec('pouchdb-server --port 5984 -m',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
        }
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed it locally then:

```
let db = spawn('node', ['./node_modules/pouchdb-server/bin/pouchdb-server', '--port', '5984', '-m']);
```